# DotNet OpenID and ASP.NET membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, dotnetopenauth

I would like to know if is possible to use DotNet OpenID together with ASP.NET membership.
Or other way or allow OpenId account in ASP.NET membership.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please see these similar questions for an answer to your question.

- [Implementing OpenID in ASP.net "Properly" - Membership or Authentication Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918156/implementing-openid-in-asp-net-properly-membership-or-authentication-provider)
- [How to integrate OpenId with ASP.Net Membership in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186573/how-to-integrate-openid-with-asp-net-membership-in-mvc/1188240)
- http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+membership+dotnetopenid+dotnetopenauth+site:stackoverflow.com/questions