# modify the asp.net membership to support open id

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, openid, asp.net-4.5

I am currently setting up my mvc 4 web application with the out of the box membership functionality included in .net.

I would like to expand this functionality to support open id providers such as facebook, twitter, my open id, dotnetopenid etc etc.

Once a user logs in with such, they have the ability to update their profile, name etc and get saved in to database same as if I had created a account with a password.

Question is I am not sure what modifications are require to support open id in the database. What information is needed to be stored to support open id? Are there any examples available of a data structure that supports both password login and open id login?

Comment: Didn't read them all, but these are the top related Google results, some are from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186573/how-to-integrate-openid-with-asp-net-membership-in-mvc , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918156/implementing-openid-in-asp-net-properly-membership-or-authentication-provide , http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/ , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx , http://danhounshell.com/blog/adding-openid-to-your-web-site-in-conjunction-with-asp-net-membership/

Comment: You could possibly look at the authentication and authorisation facilities provided with [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/): https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization