# Implementing a membership system using OpenID

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, openid

I'm looking to implement a membership system using OpenID for my ASP.NET application, similar to the system used here on StackOverflow. I'm aware that the OpenAuth library is generally recognized as the way to go, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement it.

I use NHibernate to persist my domain objects. I have a Users table with a username column, email column, etc. I'm not sure how to integrate OpenID with my own users table, and I haven't found any good tutorials on this. Does anyone have any experience with this? What is the best way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyler, yes, I found the OpenAuth library to be way too complicated (read that as "over engineered") as well. So I developed my own and made it an open source library.

you can check it out my website here
[OAuth C# Library](http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/)

I have a very simple working demo application available as well and you should be up and running in no time.

Comment: Thanks, Shiv, this looks like it could work well. Would this be easy to integrate as a membership system with my users table?

Comment: Yes it would be really simple. The library essentially handles the OAuth protocol part while giving you access to the information/data that is eventually received. So you can save that data or do anything else you desire. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx) from [Rick Strahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11197/rick-strahl).

A good write up of how to do authentication and registration with OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Implementing OpenID in ASP.net “Properly” - Membership or Authentication Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918156/implementing-openid-in-asp-net-properly-membership-or-authentication-provider) on SO. On [Codeplex](http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/) you will find a membership provider that might suite your needs. The other SO answers also share a link to a second alternative implementation.

Answer (score 0):

check it out: http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/programmatic-openid-relying-party/

very easy to implement. good luck!