# Custom Profile Provider new MVC 4 template with Dotnetopenauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, webmatrix-2

How do you now configure the membership, profile and role manager using the new MVC template with DotNetOpenAuth enabled?  I don't see the configurations in the web.config so how do you now implement a custom profile provider?

Comment: fyi - choosing the MVC 4 Basic template will give you the webconfig with the familiar membership, role, and profile settings boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new MVC4 template, it is very relevant. Instead of using a specified ProfileProvider:Profilebase, all authentication is handled by OAuth and Webmatrix.Security. Out of the box, it doesn't look like there is any support for extending Profilebase. Instead it looks like you will have to create your own table to hold any custom profile attributes. Take a look at this: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership.

Answer (score 1):

See the solution for [MVC 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/21/10339969.aspx) and built in oauth support/discussion:

See for [plugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx) custom OAuth/OpenID providers.

Comment: Also note that the built-in oauth providers for VS2012 have been updated. See  http://forums.asp.net/t/1847724.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a detailed article explaining how to [implement a profile provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5.aspx). All that you would need to do differently is plug in DotNetOpenAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Profile and role managers are independent of the mechanism used to authenticate the user and are therefore irrelevant to DotNetOpenAuth.  Only the Membership provider would be impacted by your use of DotNetOpenAuth, and [this question has been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918156/implementing-openid-in-asp-net-properly-membership-or-authentication-provide).

Comment: Understood so in the new MVC 4 template, are you saying the Profile and Role components not included?  If you try to add them the entire setup seems to fails. So there must be some correlation or collision between the Membership providers.  Just trying to get both OAUTH and Membership/Profile working in the same MVC project.

Comment: I wasn't making any statement about MVC 4.  Merely how the three ASP.NET providers relate to each other.  As for why adding them causes MVC 4 to fail, I couldn't say as I've never tried it.